# Find the largest number in a specified nested list containing numbers

Tags: python, list, nested

For example:

```
data = [[3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 3], 
        [0, 5, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 0], 
        [1, 3, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1], 
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1], 
        [1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1], 
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
        [2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 4, 3, 2, 2], 
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 3, 1, 1], 
        [2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 5, 2], 
        [3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 4]]
```

I want to print the largest number in the nested list `[2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 5, 2]` which is 5 which is contained in `index[8][8]`.

I also want to print on which index of the nested list it was in.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
data = [[3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 3], [0, 5, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 0], [1, 3, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 4, 3, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 3, 1, 1], [2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 5, 2], [3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 4]]

for lst in data:
    maximum = max(lst)
    index = [data.index(lst),lst.index(maximum)]
    print(f"Largest Number = {maximum} , Index = [{index[0]}][{index[1]}]")
```

Output:

```
Largest Number = 3 , Index = [0][0]
Largest Number = 5 , Index = [1][1]
Largest Number = 5 , Index = [2][2]
Largest Number = 4 , Index = [3][3]
Largest Number = 4 , Index = [4][4]
Largest Number = 1 , Index = [5][1]
Largest Number = 4 , Index = [6][6]
Largest Number = 3 , Index = [7][6]
Largest Number = 5 , Index = [8][8]
Largest Number = 4 , Index = [9][9]
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is good. However, if you wish to use the beauty of NumPy and python you can use the following snippet. The snippet also generalizes if there are multiple max elements.

```
import numpy as np

data = [[3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 3], 
        [0, 5, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 0], 
        [1, 3, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1], 
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1], 
        [1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1], 
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
        [2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 4, 3, 2, 2], 
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 3, 1, 1], 
        [2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 5, 2], 
        [3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 4]]

# For max value across the matrix
indices = np.where(data == data.max())
max_indices = list(zip(indices[0], indices[1]))
print(max_indices)
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (8, 8)]

# If you want it for each row
max_args = data.max(axis=1)
result = [(i,j,np.where(data[j]==i)[0][0]) for j,i in enumerate(max_args)]

print(result)
# Format (number,row,col)
[(3, 0, 0),
 (5, 1, 1),
 (5, 2, 2),
 (4, 3, 3),
 (4, 4, 4),
 (1, 5, 1),
 (4, 6, 6),
 (3, 7, 6),
 (5, 8, 8),
 (4, 9, 9)]
```